# compose node container throws: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I got this error in docker:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/home/dan/repos/test_11/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/package.json'
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  npm:
    image: node:16.13.2
    container_name: dan_npm
    volumes:
      - "./app:/home/dan/repos/test_11/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone"
    working_dir: "/home/dan/repos/test_11/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone"
    entrypoint: [ 'npm', 'start' ]
```

What do I miss?

[Image from project folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ob5g.png)

Comment: Can you show your folder structure using `tree`?

Comment: Yes, I can. From the hole system or just my test_11 folder?
I cannot load here because too long.

Comment: Your project directory, where your compose file is. Because you are issues with your volume, it seems. So it would be useful to see what exactly you are mounting.

Comment: I try to add my project folder, but I keep getting this message:
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: you can omit some things. For example you dont need to include the content of node_modules. Just the general outline of your folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you mount the /app and everything inside at the end of the path inside the container. So you are repeating the path.

By doing this.

```yaml
volumes:
  # mounts app and everything inside at the location after the colon
  - ./app:/home/dan/repos/test_11/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone
```

The final path, inside the container, will be this.

```
/home/dan/repos/test_11/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/
```

I would suggest mounting something like this.

```yaml
working_dir: /twentytwentyone
volumes:
  # mount only the relevant folder (the last one) inside /app 
  # to some location, not as deeply nested for convinience
  - ./app/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone:/twentytwentyone
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got a new Error when I docker compose up -d

```services.npm Additional property workdir is not allowed```

Comment: my bad, it was a typo I guess. Use `working_dir`.

Comment: I had the path also wrong, I copied the stuttered one. But I have fixed that. I hope you are getting the point of whats the problem here though.

Comment: @ÖrdögDániel, but this setup is quite strange anyway. I see a lot of PHP files in that folder. Are you sure there is a benefit in putting this in a node image?

Comment: I have seen the path was too long, but THANK YOU it is working now.
I am completely a novice so I am not sure exactly why I am doing this this way.

Comment: If you can suggest a better way I probably will listen and try to do it. I am learning this next to my full-time job.

Comment: Well, I dont really know PHP or wordpress so I can hardly suggest you something in this regard. I just notice that it looks a bit odd. But maybe it makes sense in the bigger picture, since you have also a wordpress container in your full setup.